# No operations defined in spec! with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I'm getting No operations defined in spec!  while loading swagger-ui on sping boot

Below are code details:

```
pom.xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>

On my main file,
   
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(
                title = "RESTAPI",
                //version = "${app.version}",
                description = "svsjsjj ssksj",
                contact = @Contact(
                            name = "bajaj", 
                            url = "https://jhakja.com"
                )
        )
)

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "io.swagger", "io.swagger.api" , "io.swagger.configuration"})
public class Swagger2SpringBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner  {

// I have sqlitcode + Date and time code,

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     new SpringApplication(Swagger2SpringBoot.class).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket customImplementation(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("io.swagger.api"))
                    .build();
    }
}
```

I just tried adding as below on my application.properties :

```
springdoc.paths-to-exclude=/swagger-resources/**      //wanted to exclude swagger-resource
springdoc.packagesToScan=io.swagger.api
springdoc.pathsToMatch=restapi/v2,restapi/v2/*
```

I have many controllers with below forms since project was generated from swagger.io -> exported as spring project -> imported the same on IDE

1. interafce :

   ```
   @Validated
   @Api(value = "alert", description = "the alert API")
   @RequestMapping(value = "/v2")
   public interface AlertApi {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Finds all alerts", nickname = "findAllAlerts", notes = "Provides list of all alerts", responseContainer = "List", authorizations = {
        @Authorization(value = "api_key"),
        @Authorization(value = "settings_auth", scopes = {
            @AuthorizationScope(scope = "write:settings", description = "modify settings in your system"),
            @AuthorizationScope(scope = "read:settings", description = "read your settings")
            })
    }, tags={ "alert", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful operation", responseContainer = "List"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid status value") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/alert/history",
        produces = {"application/json" },
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<Object>  findAllAlerts();

    }
   ```
2. class file :

   ```
     @javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2021-10-12T11:46:11.648Z")

     @Controller
     public class AlertApiController implements AlertApi {

    public ResponseEntity<Object> findAllAlerts() {
     // processing 

    }
    }
   ```

I also tried creating a single class file instead of interface and then class but that didnt work.

```
@Tag(name = "PingController", description = "This is responsible for give the status of application")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(restapi/v2)
public class PingController {


    @Operation(summary = "End-point to test ping")
    @GetMapping("/v2/ping")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getMessages() {
    //other code    
    }
}
```

I have jwt-related code as well but moved to different packages.

Not able to load the controllers. Need help on this.

[swagger ui displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLxJa.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the value of the `springdoc.pathsToMatch` property in application.properties.

Try commenting out `springdoc.pathsToMatch=restapi/v2,restapi/v2/*` in your application.properties and see if that resolves the problem. If it does, then adjust the value to something like `springdoc.pathsToMatch=restapi/v2/**`.

Answer (score 0):

just for context:
I was migrating from springfox to springdocs and I encountered the same issue.

1. I generally just added the dependencies:
   `implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.4")`
2. I made sure to add this annotation to my application:
   `@OpenAPIDefinition`
3. I then added some config to application.yml:

```
 springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    use-root-path: true
    path: /swagger-ui.html
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
```

Regarding how I came about these, I got these from springdocs migration guide and then I used the samples in springdoc as reference.

- https://github.com/springdoc
- you can see the examples here: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos
- I just checked one of the yml files and compared mine to it and found a curious line `use-root-path: true`

  - https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-book-service/src/main/resources/application.yml

I added that and my docs were populated.

I was googling regarding this issue just a while ago and just happened to get mine to work. I hope this helps.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me when my `api` package folder is not in the same app folder:

```
springboot-project
└── src
│   └──  main
│   │   └──  java
│   │       └── com
│   │            └── api <-- 
│   │            └── app
│   │                └── MyApplication.java
```

Then I put it inside of the app folder, and it worked

```
springboot-project
└── src
│   └──  main
│   │   └──  java
│   │       └── com
│   │            └── app
│   │                └── api <--
│   │                └── MyApplication.java
```

Follow this excellent tutorial for a correct configuration:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation